# estoy aprendiendo a programar y tengo que hacer un login

Tags: c#, login

tengo que hacer un login donde el usuario se guarde en un archivo y la contraseña en otro y cuando presione ingresar me mande a otra ventana lo intente hacer pero a la hora de ingresar no me manda a la otra ventana y tampoco me marca que tenga errores.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            
            FileStream archivo1 = new FileStream("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/segundo cuatrimestre/programacion/final falso/usuario.txt", FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader leerarchivo1 = new StreamReader(archivo1);
            FileStream archivo2 = new FileStream("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/segundo cuatrimestre/programacion/final falso/contraseña.txt", FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader leerarchivo2 = new StreamReader(archivo2);

            bool flag1 = false;
            bool flag2 = false;
           

            while (leerarchivo1.Peek() < -1 )
            {
                string usuario;
                usuario = leerarchivo1.ReadToEnd();
                
                if (usuario == textBox1.Text)
                {
                    
                    flag1 = true;

                }

            }

            while (leerarchivo2.Peek() < -1)
            {
                string contraseña;
                contraseña = leerarchivo2.ReadToEnd();
                if (contraseña == textBox1.Text)
                {

                    flag2 = true;

                }

            }

            if (flag1 == true && flag2 == true)
            {
                this.Hide();
                Form2 pasapantalla = new Form2();
                pasapantalla.Show();

            }

            archivo1.Close();
            leerarchivo2.Close();
            archivo1.Close();
            leerarchivo1.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código contiene un primer error y radica en que el método `ReadToEnd()`, según la documentación de .NETFramework "Lee todos los caracteres desde la posición actual hasta el final de la secuencia" y devuelve el "Resto de la secuencia, como una cadena, desde la posición actual hasta el final" del archivo, por tanto las condiciones `usuario == textBox1.Text` y `contraseña== textBox1.Text` nunca se cumplirán; suponiendo que en el archivo correspondiente, se almacenan los nombres de usuarios y las contraseñas  en lineas separadas, lo más indicado es usar el método `ReadLine()`, que lee el una linea del archivo y devuelve una cadena que contiene toda la linea.

Contiene además otro error, en las dos condiciones se compara contra el mismo valor `textBox1.Text`, si el `textBox1` es el control donde el usuario ingresara su identificador, la condición `contraseña== textBox1.Text` es incorrecta, suponiendo que la contraseña se captura en un control con la propiedad `name` igual a `textBox2`, la condición correcta seria `contraseña== textBox2.Text`.
A continuación coloco el código, como creo que seria mas conveniente plantearlo.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
          bool flag1 = false;

            using (System.IO.StreamReader leerarchivo1 = System.IO.File.OpenText("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/segundo cuatrimestre/programacion/final falso/usuario.txt")
            {
               string usuario = "";
              do
              {
                usuario = leerarchivo1.ReadLine();
                if (usuario == textBox1.Text)
                {
                  flag1 = true;
                  break;
                }
              }
              while (usuario != null)
            }

            bool flag2 = false;
            using (System.IO.StreamReader leerarchivo2 = System.IO.File.OpenText("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/segundo cuatrimestre/programacion/final falso/contraseña.txt")
            {
               string contraseña= "";
              do
              {
                contraseña= leerarchivo1.ReadLine();
                if (contraseña== textBox2.Text)
                {
                  flag2 = true;
                  break;
                }
              }
              while (contraseña!= null)
            }

        if (flag1 == true && flag2 == true)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form2 pasapantalla = new Form2();
            pasapantalla.Show();
        }
  }
```

Me he limitado a responder tu pregunta tal cual está planteada, pero hay dos consideraciones que serian contenido para otras preguntas y nuevas respuestas.

1. Almacenar los nombres de usuarios y sus contraseñas, en archivos separados, puede ser causa de errores; pues en tu código e incluso en el de mi respuesta, no se verifica que la contraseña este enlazada de manera univoca al usuario, solo se verifica que el nombre de usuario existe en el archivo `leerarchivo1` y que la contraseña existe en el archivo `leerarchivo2`, pero eso no garantiza que la contraseña sea la que el usuario actual estableció cuando creó su cuenta. Para resolver este problema, seria recomendable almacenar *nombre de usuario y contraseña* en un mismo archivo, en lineas con texto separados por un carácter o cadena predeterminado (que habría que validar como reservado, pues no podría ser usado ni en el nombre ni en la contraseña, por ejemplo puede ser separados por coma ",", pero la coma entonces no puede estar en el nombre ni en la contraseña; aunque parezca poco probable hay que validarlo, pues siempre hay un **tozudo** usuario que mete los dedos y arruina, el código que tanto te costó escribir). Solucionar esto, implica cambiar el procedimiento en que guardas *nombre de usuario y contraseña* al archivo, y además en el código  del método `button1_Click`habría que obtener la cadena y usar la función `Split` `para obtener una matriz y poder acceder al *nombre y su contraseña*; esto es tema para otra pregunta y varias respuestas.

Además, tener un archivo para usuario y otro para contraseña, genera un mayor tiempo de ejecución; tener en cuenta, que para cargar solo dos campos, *nombre de usuario y contraseña*, hay que leer dos archivos en disco, si el número de usuarios es pequeño, el tamaño del archivo también lo será y este tal ves no sea un problema, pero de todas maneras, aunque no soy experto en buenas practicas de programación (soy solo un programador autodidacta), creo que no es buena practica tener dos archivos para almacenar una información que es común.

2. El segundo problema, radica en que nunca será recomendable guardar contraseñas en archivos de texto plano, como se puede inferir del código mostrado en tu método. La solución de ese problema es mucho mas compleja que todo lo hablado hasta ahora, pues lo recomendable, es usar archivos encriptados, u otra opción de cifrado de la información, pues un simple archivo de texto plano, siempre seria muy vulnerable en términos de seguridad, un tema en el que mi experiencia, solo permite hacer esta humilde observación.

Comment: si, tengo claro que hacer eso en dos archivos separados es menos eficaz pero de donde saque el ejercicio me lo pedía así, gracias por la ayuda me sirvió.

Comment: @kevin Por nada, estamos aquí para ayudarnos.